# Label caption don't show while macro running

Tags: excel, vba, label, userform

I want to have a "Please wait" pop-up showing when running a long macro. I found out that the easiest way to do this is to have a userform that shows at the beginning and disappears at the end.
The problem I encounter is that the label inside the userform is not showing until the sub is finished...

Here's my test code. What am I missing?

```
Sub testPleaseWait()

UserForm1.Show vbModeless
Dim a As Integer
a = 0
While a < 1000
    Debug.Print a
    a = a + 1
Wend
Unload UserForm1

End Sub
```

The userform is made of only one label (called "Label1").
I tried to set the caption on the "activate" sub of the userform but that didn't help.

Thanks in advance for your answers !

Alex

Comment: try repainting the form when a=0 in the loop?

Comment: Try putting your code in the `Userform_Activate`, then call your userform from another sub.

Comment: Extending @dwirony's answer: after `.Show` control gets to `Sub UserForm1_initialize`. So have a `Sub UserForm1_initialize()`, and issue the `UserForm1.Label1 = "Please wait..."`.

Comment: Your code is running without letting time to the system to process the userform displaying. Just add a `DoEvents` after the `.Show`

Comment: @Robert Todar: in modeless state execution in caller module continues uninterruptedly. Even the `UserForm1.Label1 = "Please wait..."` assignment can be done in modul `testPleaseWait` after `.Show vbModeless`, it will do the desired behaviour.

Comment: @AcsErno That's exactly what I did but it didn't work.

Comment: @VincentG could you pleas explain thid DoEvents? I don't know about that

Comment: [DoEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/doevents-function)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your answers.

I juste added a

```
UserForm1.repaint
```

after the .Show and it worked !